# Specific Mysql Select query Help needed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `resource (id, name, ...)` and `user_favorites(user_id, resource_id)` which has foreign key `resource_id` from the resource table.

I have a situation where I need to check if resource table has any records to user_favorites table for a particular user_id in user_favorites table, and put a flag true or false accordingly.

This is the last query I could come up with

```
SELECT distinct resources.*,
       (CASE WHEN user_favorites.user_id='1' then 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) as favorite,
       user_favorites.user_id
FROM resources LEFT JOIN
     user_favorites
     ON resources.id = user_favorites.resource_id
```

However, what I want to be able to keep the resources. With the current query, it records false when there are records for other user ids also.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Syntax error. Missing comma after resources.*.

Comment: one way is this: you'd need a WHERE clause to restrict to the desired user ID. In the CASE you can then just check whether favourites.user_id is null or not. Haven't tested that obviously but I'm fairly sure it would work.

Comment: @jarlh Corrected. Thanks

Comment: @ADyson I want to be able to show all resource records without restricting the ID, but be able to put up a flag TRUE or FALSE based on whether there are any records on the user favorites table for that particular ID

Comment: Add example data and expected results as text formatted data table we are geussing here.. Place the SQL example data on sqlfiddle.com or db-fiddle.com

Comment: @KavindaKeshanRasnayake I suggested to restrict on the _user_ ID not the resource ID. Since you used a left join to the favourites table, then my suggestion should achieve that. The table (resources in this case) on the left side of the join will always have all rows listed. Then you'll get a result true/false for each resource according to whether the requested user has a favourite record associated with it. Gordon's answer below is also a viable approach of course.

Comment: @ADyson I found Gordon's answer to be more viable for my use. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expression logic in the `select`.  In MySQL, you don't even need `case`:

```
SELECT r.*, 1 as user_id,
       (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM user_favorites uf
                WHERE r.id = ur.resource_id AND
                      ur.user_id = 1
               )
       ) as flag
FROM resources r ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I will accept the answer in 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT 
r.*
, IFNULL(ur.totalUser, 0) AS totalUser
FROM `resource` r
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    resource_id
    , COUNT(user_id) AS totalUser
    FROM `user_favourites` 
    GROUP BY resource_id
) AS ur ON ur.resource_id = r.`id`
```